# unable to list "extensions/v1beta1, resource=ingresses

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, federated-learning

I was trying to use `kubeFate` with version `1.3.0` but after I applied the service with its original file as `kubectl apply -f ./kubefate.yaml`, it pops out the error saying

```
Error from server (NotFound): Unable to list "extensions/v1beta1, Resource=ingresses": the server could not find the requested resource (get ingresses.extensions)
```

Initially I looked into the `kubefate.yaml` and changed anything related to `extensions/v1beta1` in the ingress part as:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
   name: kubefate
   namespace: kube-fate
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: kubefate.net
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                 name: kubefate
                 port:
                   number: 8080
```

Well, after changed, it does not generate the error when I apply but after I use `kubectl get all,ingress -n kube-fate` to check out the status, the same error shows again...
I have no clue how to solve this. Please someone give me some hint.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it has nth to do with the problem I expect. I change another way to initiate the `minikube` from `minikube start --vm-driver=none`  to `minikube start --vm-driver=none --kubernetes-version v1.19.0`. Then the problem is solved